# BinaryFormatter tries to serialize a form instead of an object

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a DTO class which looks something like this:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract()]
public class MyClass : IEntity, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [DataMember()]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

All my DTO classes and their properties have the same attributes. Only this class has `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

I also have a generic extension which compares 2 objects (can be complex object graphs):

```
public static bool IsEqual<T>(this T object1, T object2)
{
    byte[] array1 = object1.ToByteArray();
    byte[] array2 = object2.ToByteArray();

    return array1.SequenceEqual(array2);
}
```

The above method is being used throughout the whole app without any problems. However, on this one particular class, I'm getting the following exception:

> Type 'MyProject.MyForm' in Assembly 'MyProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.

I've checked and re-checked my code, and there is no place where I'm passing a form to the extension.

I don't want to serialize the form. I want to serialize an object (which is a local variable in the form itself, as with all other forms I have). Also, debugging the above extension shows that both parameters are of the same and expected type.

As this is the only class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, could the problem be with this interface?

Comment: Could you add a manual serializer to MyProject.MyForm, mark it as Serializable, put a break point in the manual serializer, and then you can see what's triggering the attempt to serialize that object? ("Custom Serialization using ISerializable" - http://kb4dev.com/tutorial/.net-framework-classes-using-csharp/binary-serializer - for an example.)

Comment: Ah, so probably MyForm is subscribed to property changed event and so is present in internal list of event subscribers which also gets serialized, as Hans says.

Comment: @HansPassant [NonSerialized] on the event shows a compiler error that it is only valid on field declarations. Also, I need to implement property changed only on this class. Usually my DTO's are really POCO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BinaryFormatter will also serialize the backing field for the event.  Strange as that may seem, this sometimes actually works.  But not if a Form object subscribed the event, it is not a serializable class.  Fix:

```
  [field:NonSerialized]
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

Which *does* force you to think how that event needs to be subscribed when you deserialize the object.  There is no universal guidance, other than that it is always a good idea to keep serializable data in a POD class without any bells and whistles.  Makes them a lot easier to reason about and much easier to maintain without drastic version headaches.

Comment: This fix is working. In my case I'm never deserializing back. I just serialize the object just to compare the current object with the original object.

Comment: You are bound to regret this some more later.  You can't use `decimal` as a member for example.